# When the Return Value Optimization Required/Apply?

Tags: c++

I'm little confused about Return value optimization, Here is the example.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    int x;
    public:
        A(int val=0):x(val){
            cout << "A" << x << endl;
        }
        A(const A& a){
            x=a.x;
            cout << "B " << x << endl;
        }
        void SetX(int x){
            this -> x=x;
        }
        ~A(){
            cout << "D " << x << endl;
        }
};
A f(A a){
    cout << "C " << endl;
    a.SetX(100);
    return a;
}
int main(){
    A a(1);
    A b=f(a); // Why Copy constructor instead of RVO?
    b.SetX(-100);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
A 1 // ok
B 1 // ok
C // ok
B 100 // why it's here? Why copy constructor instead of RVO?
D 100 // why after the above line? it should be before the above line.
D -100 // ok 
D 1 // ok
```

I'm little confused about the B 100 and D 100 outputs.

1) Why compiler give `B 100` output it should be `RVO` ( copy constructor should not called ).

2) The second one is that if copy constructor is called then `D 100` should be before the `B 100` because in `fun()` function object is going out of scope. before `A b=f(a);` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVO or more specifically, named return value optimization (NRVO), is a type of copy elision, which according to the standard is permitted under the following circumstances[12.8/31]:

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
>   non-volatile automatic object (**other than a function** or catch-clause **parameter**) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>   the automatic object directly into the function’s return value [emphasis mine]

So, RVO is not permitted in this case because `a` is a function parameter.

Before the function ends but after it has taken a copy of `a` for the return value it must destroy the temporary variable `a`.

Comment: Note that it was permitted in C++03, this restriction was introduced in C++11 for no good reason except that it is hard to implement.

Comment: @Chris you mean compiler will copy `a` object to `b` then it will destroy to `a`?

Comment: @LetDoIt Effectively,  yes.

Comment: @ChrisDrew why Copy constructor and Destructor for `A b=fun();` is not called in this code http://codepaste.net/rb98wj in `DEV C++`? even the above code is same (except value). and calling destructor and copy constructor for `b object`.

Comment: @LetDoIt in that case `obj` is not a function parameter so NRVO is permitted according to the standard.

Comment: @ChrisDrew But Visual Studio 2013 is calling the Copy constructor and Destructor for `A b;`

Comment: @LetDoIt It doesn't for me. Are you running a Release build?

Comment: @ChrisDrew I don't know about release build, I just use CTRL+F5. How to run code in best way?

Comment: @LetDoIt if you want Visual Studio to optimize your code so it runs fast you have to click where it says Debug at the top and change it to Release.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, RVO is NEVER required. It is allowed, which makes it a big difference.

EDIT.

My initial answer was incorrect regarding sequence of constructors. I missed the line in the output, and indeed, it simply means that copy elision didn't hapen fully. Out of 3 sematic copies (from f() to temporary location by means of return a; from temporary location to right-hand side of b=f(a); from that right-hand side to the b) one was not elided and copied in full. I have no idea which was it.

Comment: The copy due to the pass-by-value into `f` is not the one OP is asking about. OP is asking about the second copy.

Comment: I have edited my question to try to answer this. Makes sense now?

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, You mean `fun()'s` object destroy when calling statement ends? mean object destroy when `A b=f(a);` end?

Comment: It actually is destroyed before that. Think about it this way - compiler inserts call to destructor right before } in your f().

Comment: @SergeyA Again confused, then why copy constructor `B 100` before the destructor? `D 100` :( :(

Comment: OK, I might need to look at it for a sec. I misread the output. I will update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why compiler give B 100 output it should be RVO ( copy constructor should not called ).

Yes, it should be called, because you're getting a copy of `a` as parameter.

> D 100

happens because after the return statement, `a` goes out of scope.

Comment: you mean Object goes out of scope after the statement? mean after this statement? `A b=f(a);` therefore copy constructor called before the destructor?

Comment: No, I mean it like I wrote it: in `f`, after `return a`, `a` goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes.. then why D 100 after the B 100 ? if `return a` goes out of scope. then D 100 called after that Copy constructor should called. did you understand my question?

Comment: Hey, you fixed your answer before I can comment on it :)

Comment: @SergeyA: yeah, that was a typo. I was making coffee with half of my brain. aaaah coffeee....

Comment: @MarcusMüller the last one is that RVO will perform when I return a temporary object from Function? like this one. `return A(100);` Mean RVO is for just temporary objects?

Comment: as @SergeyA said, RVO doesn't really necessarily happen.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok would you like to read the last 2 comments on SergeyA's answer? and can you clear my confusion about that.